# Not able to import component from the remote app to host app while using vite module fedaration to share component

Tags: reactjs, vite

This is `vite.config.ts` for host app

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "app",
      remotes: {
        remoteApp: "http://localhost:3003/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
  ],
  mode: "development",
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
})
```

This is `vite.config.ts` file for remote app

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "remote_app",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Button": "./src/Button",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
  ],
  mode: 'development',
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});
```

getting error while importing Button from remote app to the host app, App.tsx file

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
import { Button } from 'remoteApp/Button' <---- //getting error here, not able to find out Button component

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React + Host app</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <Button />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

this is the Button component

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Button = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me: {count}</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Getting error in console of host app is

```
__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:338 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at yh (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:338:64)
    at J (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:196:401)
    at Yi (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:227:323)
    at Wk (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:328:319)
    at Vk (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315:393)
    at Uk (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315:322)
    at Jk (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315:181)
    at Hk (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:303:209)
    at J (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:25:204)
    at MessagePort.R (__federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:26:129)
yh @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:338
J @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:196
Yi @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:227
Wk @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:328
Vk @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315
Uk @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315
Jk @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:315
Hk @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:303
J @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:25
R @ __federation_shared_react-dom-c0b5c364.js:26
```

I tired so many videos to do module federation and did exactly same setup but still getting error. Im expecting to successfully share the Button from remote to host app.